# Batch/cmd: stop glassfish, copy file, start glassfish

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, glassfish

My objective is fairly simple. I have a glassfish server. I made a change to the jar which I need to put into the domains/lib folder. For that I have to stop-domain, copy the file over, then start domain. I thought using batch file would be a fairly efficient way to do that; however, I seem to be struggling.

Here is what I've got

```
REM ##### Set paths #####
SET glassfish_home=C:\glassfish-4.1\bin
SET target_folder=C:\dummypath\target
SET domain_lib=C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
SET jar=dummyfile.jar
PAUSE

REM ##### Stop glassfish server #####
cd %glassfish_home%
asadmin stop-domain

REM ##### Copy DataAccess jar #####
cd %target_folder%
COPY %jar% %domain_lib%\

REM ##### Start glassfish server #####
cd %glassfish_home%
asadmin start-domain
```

However, what is happening right now is it seems to stop the domain, but does not proceed to do anything else. Definitely doesn't start it again.

I've attempted to comment out stop-domain and just manually stopped it. I then ran the batch file and it copied the file, started the domain, but it did not close and remained on the cmd screen with "Command start-domain executed successfully." message.

Any insight into why my batch file doesn't all run smoothly, is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asadmin` is actually a batch-file, invoking it directly makes it replace the currently executed batch file (yours).

Use `call asadmin stop-domain` and `call asadmin start-domain` instead.